# Import data from one list into another

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, custom-list, app

Say I have a list A with personal information of my employees. How can I import parts of this information (e.g. the names) conditionally (e.g. all names longer than 6 letters) into another list B?
Do I need a special column type?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in many ways, depending on the need. Check for the following first

- Should this happen instantly when any new item is added in List A?
- Is this is a one time operation?
- Should this happen even when an item is updated in List A?

Following are few approaches which can be followed.

- Event Receivers : Create remote event receivers for ItemAdded and ItemUpdated events on List A. Use CSOM to make the entries to list B.
- A scheduled job : Create a application which uses CSOM, which reads all the items from List A, and copies the required content to List B. Schedule this application to run on a specified interval.